# Is it possible to create an Ubuntu 14.04 distro even though remastersys is gone?

Tags: 14.04, unity, remastersys, uck, relinux

Im trying to create my own Ubuntu distribution Im using remastersys to create backups of my system just incase it crashes which has been helpful. Now I'm done building it and I click the button that saves the config files then dist mode (whitch makes a clean install that saves my configurations), then I test it in virtual machine and it only saves the themes which I manually replaces the Ubuntu themes but not the configurations I've made with compizconfig settings manager or (ccsm), Ubuntu tweak, and unity tweak tool. I have tried suse studious but i would still run into the same dilemma, I've tried relinux and that dose the same thing as remastersys ,and I've tried UCK, thanks to the Ubuntu Community for helping me with this problem and if this problem gets fixed I will post a youtube video on how to fix it so that others can see and I'll make a shoutout to the author of the fix.